# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: java, android, xml, runtimeexception

I'm getting the following error on my app from a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.4. The app works fine on most other mobile devices but this one complains all the time.

**Error at line 91:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yitter.android/com.yitter.profile.UserProfileActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040021
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040021
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2060)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3289)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1876)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.yitter.profile.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:91)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my XML for the activity it complains about:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/drawer_item_profile"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/highlight"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/userProfileLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/notifications_message"
            android:id="@+id/noNotificationsMessage"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:onClick="LaunchFeed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_no_notifications"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/noNotificationsImage"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="LaunchFeed"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/notifications_prompt"
            android:id="@+id/noNotificationsMessage2"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:onClick="LaunchFeed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/userProfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/add_profile_picture"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_pic_add"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile_picture" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio"
            android:layout_below="@id/fullName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:paddingRight="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/websiteLink"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/highlight"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bae"
            android:layout_below="@id/websiteLink"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textColor="#e91e63"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:paddingRight="15dp" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/bae"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_feed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/networkOfflineText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reconnect_button"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@color/highlight"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also get the same error on on this activity, which has basically identical XML. There must be a commonality between the two that is causing the crash.

**Error at line 87:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yitter.android/com.yitter.market.MarketFeedActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001d
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001d
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2060)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3289)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1876)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.yitter.market.MarketFeedActivity.onCreate(MarketFeedActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    ... 11 more
```

And here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@color/highlight"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/checkFilePermission"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/file_permissions"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="enableFilePermission"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/elgamiteal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <ListView
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_feed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/networkOfflineText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reconnect_button"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@color/highlight"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

One thing I noticed is that my production build only has `layout-v21` as possible layout types. I probably have to include `layout` and `layout-sw720dp` to get this working, eh?

Comment: Look for the first line in each error message that contains a class which you created. The line number where the error occurs is listed at the end of that line in the error message. Please indicate which line this is for each error.

Comment: I got this from a crash report and unfortunately don't have access to the phone itself. :(

Comment: But you have access to the code, right?

Comment: Yes I do. Oh I guess I can run in emulator?

Comment: Yes...but that's beside the point. In order to help you, I need to know exactly which line causes the problem. I have given you instructions how to determine this. Please edit your question to indicate the exact line.

Comment: I can't tell from your instructions which line I need to identify.

Comment: Follow the instructions in my first comment: "Look for the first line in the stack trace that contains the name of a class which you created."

Comment: Okay sorry. I updated it.

Comment: It's pointing to ``setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);`` and ``setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);``

Comment: It can't find a resource... So all the `@color`, `@string`, `@drawable`, and `@dimen` need to be defined.

Comment: Open `activity_profile.xml` and `activity_feed.xml` to look for errors in Android Studio. They will be marked with a red underline.

Comment: There aren't any errors in the xml though. At least marked ones.